# use macro in doxygen that relies on etoolbox package

Tags: formula, doxygen, tex

I have a macro defined as

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} %to use \ifstrempty

\newcommand{\ISet}[1][]
{
    \ifstrempty{#1}
        {\mathfrak{i}}
        {\mathfrak{i}_{#1}}
}
```

which relies on the etoolbox package.

Is there a way to use this macro in doxygen?

EDIT (provided a MWE):

```
# configuration file
FORMULA_MACROFILE      = ./macros.tex
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRA_PACKAGES = etoolbox amsfonts
INPUT                  = ./mwe.cc
```

macros.tex

```
\newcommand{\pr}[1][]{
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{%
p%
}{%
p_{#1}%
}%
}
```

mwe.cc

```
/**
*  \f$  \pr[1] , \pr  \f$
*/
int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

Gives wrong output, see the picture

[image]

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you give a bit a more extensive example where you want to use the given `FORMULA_MACROFILE `

Comment: Note the documentation also states that only `newcommand` and `renewcommand` are allowed in the macrofile. For the `usepackage` (here `etoolbox`) you have to use the `EXTRA_PACKAGES` setting also the "validation" is quite buggy.

Comment: @albert I use doxygen 1.9.0, but would be flexible for upgrading. I want to use the macro to document my code, e.g, do something like \f$ \ISet[1] \f$.

Comment: @albert But even if I were able to use the EXTRA_PACKAGES to somehow include the etoolbox package, I can not use my macro as it has optional arguments, right?

Comment: The current version of doxygen is 1.9.7 so it is always wise to udate although it won't solve your problems. It looks like there are some issues using the macro. Forgot to ask before, which output format?

Comment: Note: I also some problems regarding the path of the `FORMULA_MACROFILE` for this is created the proposed patch https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/10189

Comment: The code for the `FORMULA_MACROFILE` has been integrated into the master version of doxygen

Comment: What do you mean by "the code for the FORMULA_MACROFILE" ?

Comment: The patch as mentioned in the comment i.e.  https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/10189

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the proposed doxygen patch https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/10189 in the current doxygen master version (using an absolute path at the moment would probably also work) the settings:

```
QUIET = YES
EXTRA_PACKAGES = etoolbox amsfonts
FORMULA_MACROFILE = mymacro.sty
```

and

the `FORMULA_MACROFILE`

```
\newcommand{\ISet}[1][]
{
    \ifstrempty{#1}
        {\mathfrak{i}}
        {\mathfrak{i}_{#1}}
}
```

it all looks like to work.

**Edit**
Given the example from the question I get for HTML:

[image]

and for Latex:

[image]

This looks all OK to me.

- Where should I look for the problem?

Comment: My macro file is of format .tex. If I place a newcommand with optional argument(s), I get a warning and all latex formatting results in "Undefined symbol...". Why does it work for you?

Comment: When I have a MWE i.e. the doxygen settings different from the defaults (i.e. `doxygen -x Doxyfile`), a small source code example and  the `FORMULA_MACROFILE` so I can reproduce your problem I might be able to answer it. It might also be because of the path problem with the FORMULA_MACROFILE, but now my crystal ball doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: I could provide you a MWE if there were a chance for a solution. But as you said, the documentation (of the latest version) states that the macros are restricted to cases without optional arguments. Clearly, a macro with optional argument does not work then. So do you think it makes sense to discuss this further?

Comment: 1) well you mention that the example I provided didn't work for you (or as far as I can see you suggested it) so this is already to see what you did differently. 2) without a MWE we won't be able to know / see what we need to correct so another good reason to provide a MWE. Also not knowing which output format you use doesn't help...

Comment: I provided a MWE which demonstrates the problems.

Comment: I just updated my answer, looks all OK to me.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: For the test I used doxygen 1.9.0 but also with doxygen 1.9.7 I get the same results. Do Show the output you got and indicate what is wrong! Question is which version of latex, dvips and gs are you using?

Comment: I attached a picture in my question how the output in my case looks like. I use Tex Live 2022/dev/Debian , dvips 2021.1 (Tex Live 2022/dev) and gs version 9.55.0. My doxygen version is 1.8.20. Do you have an idea what might be the problem? The macro works fine in any .tex document.

Comment: I see the repeated / mirrored informatiion. From a previous comment I was under the impression you used 1.9.0 but also with the 1.8.20 version I see correct results. I remember that there have been, regular, problems with ghostscript but I don't remember which ones . I tested most of the times with 9.50 but also I did some tests with 10.00.0 (thought in the past we had some problems with 10.01.1)

Comment: As I said, if I use the macro in a tex document, the output is OK like in your picture. Only the html output is not OK. So do you think the problem is related to ghostscript?

Comment: I assume that you mean with "I use the macro in a tex document" this is not a doxygen part / related and that you directly use `*latex` on it. When you generated the doxygen output there is also a latex directory and when you go into this and run `make`  the result after the `make` is a `refman.pdf`, please inspect this file. My current guess is indeed ghostscript, the formulas in the HTML output (contrary to the latex / pdf output) use `latex` / `dvips` and `gs` (and some intermediate processing) so the latex test test might give a clue as well.

Comment: Inspecting the file `refman.pdf´ gives the same correct output that you posted. So would you suggest me to use a different version of ghostscript to narrow down the problem further?

Comment: That is good news. Yes please use a different version of ghostscript.

Comment: Should I use ghostscript 10.00.0 ? And is there a way to pass the path to ghostscript to doxygen? I would keep my current version then in case the new version does not work.

Comment: You should be able to use 10.00.0. There is no way to do this but maybe you can accomplish something with symbolic links or with an intermediate script that calls the right executable.

Comment: I mixed certain things yesterday, so even with ghostscript 9.55.0 the output in HTML is OK. But, interestingly, if you take the same example and add "USE_MATHJAX=YES" to the config file, then I receive the warning "file contains non-valid code, expected { but got [" and the output in HTML is an undefined control sequence at the place of the macro. Can you reproduce that?

Comment: I could reproduce the `MATHJAX` "problem". Indeed `MATHJAX` is a problem as `MATHJAX` does not support optional arguments, you probably have to do there something like `\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}}{} ....` to check for empty arguments (might also mean that just `\pr` is not possible and you have to use `\pr{}`.

Comment: But if I do not use MATHJAX, I can work with optional arguments? I mean it obviously works, however, the docu explicitly states " restricted to a version without optional parameters  ". So is the documentation not up-to-date in this regard?

Comment: It looks indeed that the mentioned `FORMULA_MACROFILE` was described for use with `MATHJAX` but it also works for non-`MATHJAX` usage (as it is mentioned, "image version"), so the documentation might need some update.

Comment: Alright, maybe its worth to create a pull-request for an improvement of the docu.